# HTML5 input's "min" attribute is not graying out calendar's past dates

Tags: html, date, input, attributes, min

I know it's a fairly common and repetitive question but I haven't found a solution nor a explicit reason why this is happening and I'm getting frustrated with something so simple yet important.

I have a `form` with an `<input type=date />` whose `min` attribute varies depending on the current date. I have this JS routine to determine the current date and then modify the `input type=date`

```
let today = new Date();
let day = today.getDate();
let month = today.getMonth()+1;
let year = today.getFullYear();

today = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

console.log(today)

const calendarInput = document.getElementById('to-do-date');
calendarInput.min = today;
```

When I check Chrome's Elements Console, my `input` tag looks like this

```
<input type="date" id="to-do-date" name="to-do-date" min="2020-8-31" required> <!-- That's date that I'm writing this-->
```

Pretty straight-forward, right?

But when I go to my form for the actual date input on my `form`, I get this

[Input's calendar not graying out previous dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdmPG.png)

In the image, you can see that my calendar is not graying out the dates previous to my `min` attribute which is, as today, `2020-08-31`, even though I explicitly stated to take today's date and put it as a `min` attribute and I have used different validation methods to prevent users from entering past dates but to no avail.

If you guys know the reason behind this and share it, I will truly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you need to have "*yyyy-mm-dd*" format, but now you have "*yyyy-m-d*" format. So you need to add a little function, which will correct your date:

```
const correctDate = (date) => date < 10 ? '0' + date : date;

today = year + '-' + correctDate(month) + '-' + correctDate(day);
```

I hope, this will help you!

Comment: YES! It works. Thank you. I totally missed to check the actual format.

Answer (score 0):

try to make it so that the dates are in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`
So instead of `2020-8-31` make it `2020-08-31`